# Inverting $a+b\sqrt{2}$ in the field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have been reading through my notes and I came across this example and I found it hard to understand so I need some help in explaining how the inverse of this is found.

The set $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)=\{a+b\sqrt2$: $a,b$ in $\mathbb Q \}$ is a field. The inverse of an element $a+b\sqrt 2$ in $ \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2$) is

$$\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{2}}=\frac{a}{a^2-2b^2}+\frac{-b}{a^2-2b^2}\sqrt{2} $$

Can anyone explain  to how the inverse was found? Appreciate your help.

Comment: I edited ( adding Latex tags ) to part of the text, but I am not sure of what pow 2 means . Could you please tell us?

Comment: @user99680 It means taken to the power of $2$.

Comment: @sea turtles: I see, thanks. I suspected it was not 'prisoner of war' :).

Comment: @user9968o am trying to say a square :)

Comment: @seaturtles I'm interested in the algebra of prisoners of war.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Consider an arbitrary element $a + b \sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$.  From our experience with real numbers, we know that its inverse will be $\displaystyle \frac{1}{a + b\sqrt{2}}$.  However, this is not in the "standard" form for elements in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] = \{x + y\sqrt{2} \ | \  x, y \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.

To get this into the desired form, multiply the purported inverse by $\displaystyle \frac{a - b\sqrt{2}}{a - b\sqrt{2}}$.  Doing so, we get:

$$\frac{1}{a + b\sqrt{2}} \cdot \Bigg(\frac{a - b\sqrt{2}}{a - b\sqrt{2}}\Bigg) \ = \ \frac{a-b\sqrt{2}}{a^2 - 2b^2} \ = \ \frac{a}{a^2 - 2b^2} + \Bigg(\frac{-b}{a^2-2b^2}\Bigg)\sqrt{2}$$

And this is indeed what we want since $\displaystyle \frac{a}{a^2 -2b^2}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{-b}{a^2 - 2b^2}$ are rational numbers.

Comment: Thanks Kaj Hansen this answer is really helpful

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

The standard technique: multiply numerator and denominator by conjugate.

Answer (score 1):

try solving this
$$ax+2by=1$$$$bx+ay=0$$

if $s=a+b\sqrt2$, $t=x+y\sqrt2$
then $s\cdot t=1$

do not forget the conditions over $a$, $b$ and $a^2-2b^2$.

Comment: This is an old question which already has a nice answer.  What does your answer bring to the party?

Comment: because the method of multiplying by the conjugate does not bring the conditions over $a$ , $b $and $a^2−2b^2$