# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})=\{a+b\sqrt{2}|a,b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to prove $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})=\{a+b\sqrt{2}|a,b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$.  I have proved that $\{a+b\sqrt{2}|a,b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is indeed a field with unit.  However is this enough to show that this is indeed equivilant to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: What can be said about the number $(\sqrt{2})^n$? Hence, what can be said about $P(\sqrt{2})$ if $P(x) := a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n$ where the $a_i \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: How is $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)$ defined?

Comment: Where $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is the field of $\mathbb{Q}$ with all possible unions of $\sqrt{2}$ under the operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $t^2-2$, so that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=2$. A basis of the $2$-dimensional vector space
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $(1,\sqrt{2})$, which is easy to see. Hence every element has the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$. To verify that it is a field has been done on MSE already, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821260/inverting-ab-sqrt2-in-the-field-bbb-q-sqrt2).

Comment: That makes since, and I have already shown that this is a field.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{2})$ is defined to be the intersection of every subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains $\sqrt{2}$. As such it is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ and is  contained in every subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains $\sqrt{2}$. So if you have shown that $\{ a+b \sqrt{2} : a,b \in  \mathbb{Q} \}$ is a field (which clearly has $\sqrt{2}$ as one of its elements) you have shown $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{2}) \subseteq \{ a+b \sqrt{2} : a,b \in  \mathbb{Q} \}$. To show the inclusion the other way you need to show why $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{2})$ must contain every rational as well as $\sqrt{2}$. Then since $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{2})$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ it must contain any sum and product of such elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that $\{a+b\sqrt{2}\} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, and that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \subseteq \{a+b\sqrt{2}\}$.

Then it follows that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) = \{a+b\sqrt{2}\}$. So you don't have to prove that $\{a+b\sqrt{2}\}$ has unit and inverse, if it equals a field then it definitely already has those.